# Microsoft DS vulnerability?

Tags: ports, tcp, microsoft

I heard that Microsoft DS is a port that is commonly used by hackers to hack computers due to its ability to transfer files.

1. How do they transfer files with Microsoft DS?
2. Do they need an exploit to let the malware run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft DS is the name given to port 445 which is used by SMB ([Server Message Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)). SMB is a network protocol used mainly in Windows networks for sharing ressources (e.g. files or printers) over a network. It can also be used to remotely execute commands.

You use it basically every time you use Windows to access a file share, a printer, or any other ressource located on the network.

Over time, there were a lot of vulnerabilities found in the SMB implementation of Windows, some of which allowed for execution of arbitrary commands over the network, partly without any authentication. Also very common are weak configurations of SMB in networks that provide an easy attack surface.
Together these points lead to SMB being a major attack point.

An open source implementation of SMB exists with the name of [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)), which is commonly used to easily use Linux and Windows together in a network.